# Html canvas is not fit to pdf page using html2pdf library

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, html2pdf

The requirement is to convert HTML page to pdf. I used html canvas in my html page to show graphical representation in my html page. Trying to convert the pages into pdf but html canvas is not fit to pdf page.

```
var opt = {
   margin:[1,0,1,0],
   filename:     'myfile.pdf',
   image:        { type: 'png', quality: 0.95 },
   html2canvas:  { scale: 1 },
   jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
}; 

html2pdf().from(data[0]).set(opt).save();
```

Actual Full Image:

[image]

Half Image:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Problem is full image is not fit on page. Attached is the half image on pdf file.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: try setting width and height in html2canvas object manually: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/